# Webhook trigger issue: Undefined offset: 0 in PHP from JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json, webhooks

Ok, I am stuck. Here is what I have:

```html
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// include script configuration
require_once 'config.php';

//Retrieving Webhook

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');


$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);


//Gathering Data Variables


$order_id = $data[0]["order"]["id"];
$email = $data[0]["order"]["billing_address"]["email"];
$total = $data[0]["order"]["total"];
$paid = $data[0]["order"]["status"];

//print_r($data[0]["order"]["billing_address"]["email"]);

//Knack API PUT Script

  global $kn_appID;
  global $kn_APIKey;

    // Create an array of the fields being included in the call

    $jsonarray["field_1032"] = $order_id;
    $jsonarray["field_1033"] = array("email" => $email);
    $jsonarray["field_1034"] = $total;
    $jsonarray["field_1035"] = $paid;



    //Encode array into json

    $jsonstring = json_encode($jsonarray);


    //Update the record in Knack

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.knack.com/v1/objects/object_62/records/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonstring);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "X-Knack-Application-Id: " . $kn_appID, "X-Knack-REST-API-Key: " . $kn_APIKey));
    $returnVal = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));



?>
```

ok so here is the deal, when I set the variable with the same json that I am getting when I use requestb.in as my endpoint it works fine. However, when using `file_get_contents('php://input');` I am getting this error:

Status: HTTP 200 OK: **Notice**: Undefined offset: 0 in **/home3/nzshumate/public_html/bc/get_info.php** on line **21**

Any direction on what I am doing wrong here would be appreciated.

Comment: I have also tried to change the code to `$order_id = $data->order->id;` . etc.. still no luck and get a HTTP 200 OK: <b>Warning</b>: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: What is the content of $json variable. It should be a valid json string. You can check with echo $json